# In TornadoFX, how can I separate layouts to different classes and then use them in builder?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

For example, I want to have a TabPane, but I want to have tabs each in its separate class. Is there a way to make this work with the builder? I want to do something like this:

```
tabpane {
    MyFirstTab()
    MySecondTab()
    etc.
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a general basis you add the root node from another `View` with the `add` command:

```
add(SomeView::class)
```

You can also inject a `View` and add it:

```
val someView: SomeView by inject()

override val root: borderpane {
    center {
        add(someView)
    }
}
```

`add` is the same as doing `this += someView`. What happens here is that the framework find the `root` node of the View and appends it to the `children` property of the parent Node. It also knows about special containers like the `BorderPane`, so it does the right thing when you add something inside the `center` builder etc.

The `TabPane` however, takes `Tab` instances, which are not nodes. You need to add the tab using the `tab` builder and assign some content to it. The builders are smart enought to understand that if you do `add` inside a Tab, it should assign to the `content` property of the Tab. Therefore you can write:

```
tab("My First Tab") {
    add(MyFirstTab::class)
}
```

Or if you already have an instance of the content you'd like to assign:

```
tab("My First Tab") {
    add(myFirstTab)
}
```

The `MyFirstTab` class must be a `View` or `Fragment`.